# How to display query result in rockmongo by using execute method

Tags: mongodb, rockmongo

I executed a command in mongo.exe

```
> db.tablebusiness.find({"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"});
```

I got results:

Now I try similar command in rockmongo.
If I execute

```
db.tablebusiness.find(
    {"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"}
    );
```

Result:

```
{
   "retval": null,
   "ok": 1
}
```

Basically it seems to tell me that the result is ok or something like that? I am not sure.

If I elaborate:

```
var cur = db.tablebusiness.find(
{"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"}
);
cur.forEach(function(x){print(tojson(x))});
```

Result:

```
{
   "retval": null,
   "ok": 1
}
```

Same problem.

If I do:

```
function () {
   return db.tablebusiness.find({"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"});
}
```

What does it mean by hello.tablebusiness -> undefined is beyond me. As you see from above, I successfully execute the query just fine in mongo.exe

Looks like rockmongo has very limited feature. I wonder how to actually see result. How to execute random mongodb command in rockmongo and observe the result.

Comment: Looks like it can't find the actual data you're looking for. Have you verified that it exists in the MongoDB database?

Comment: yes. I actually want something more flexible than their query feature.

Comment: You mean retval: null means there is no result returned? I will try db.tablebusiness.find() then.

Comment: okay updated. The same query run fine on mongo.exe

Comment: I'll try asking in stackoverflow then.

Comment: try :
return db.tablebusiness.find( {"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"} ); it's looks like rockmongo some times run a command in an anonymous function...

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I've tried?

Answer (score 1):

The [`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) method returns a [cursor object](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor). In order to view the first returned record in the cursor you must call the `next()` method.

```
function () {
  return db.tablebusiness.find({
    "_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"
  }).next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through and list out all of the items returned by the cursor from `find()`, I used something like this:

```
function () {
  var cur = db.tablebusiness.find({
    "_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"
  });
  var result = [];
  cur.forEach(function(item) {
    result.push(item);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Since you need to actually `return` the value in order to view it in rockmongo I just append each result to an array and return the array. This may be why the `print(tojson(x))` code you used in your loop does not give the desired result.

You can also try using the aggregation method, and just pipeline a single `$match` query, like so:

```
function () {
  return db.tablebusiness.aggregate([
    { $match: {
      "_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"
    }}
  ]);
}
```